# jsoup enhanced forloop doesnt work sometimes

Tags: java, jsoup

I have written a jsoup parser and when i run the below enhanced for loop , some times it scrapes the data and most of the  times it just skips the first line of for loop even though the data is present

It doesn't even print sysout some times that is inside the forloop.

If i run for 10 times , it just executed 3-4 times and remaining it just skips.

I have debugged and the line just goes to for (Element row : alldocument.select(".listing-details-address

> h2[itemprop='streetAddress']"))

and it doesnt goes inside the for loop.

No expection thrown and I am unable to find the error

```
for (Element row : alldocument.select(".listing-details-address 
 h2[itemprop='streetAddress']")) {
 system.out.print("inside enhance for loop")
 propadd.add(row.text());
}
```

could you please help

Comment: Can you provide us an url you are parsing or structure of your html?

Comment: <h2 itemprop="streetAddress">St Vincent Court, 5 Hoy Street E16</h2>

Comment: some its it scrapes but some time it wont for the same html page.I tried giving sleeps and other wait but it simple skips them

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ' in your selector syntax.

.listing-details-address h2[itemprop=streetAddress]

Reference:
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax